# How to previous day from an array in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have an array in bash with the following entries

```
arr=(WEDNESDAY TUESDAY SATURDAY)
```

Now i have to return the previous day (according to the week and should be present in the array) for the input.

```
input     ==> output
SATURDAY  ==> WEDNESDAY
TUESDAY   ==> SATURDAY
WEDNESDAY ==> TUESDAY
SUNDAY    ==> Null
```

Comment: What would be the output for WEDNESDAY?

Comment: it will be tuesday (the previous day as per the array)

Answer (score 2):

I would create an associative array to hold the mapping: (requires bash 4)

```
arr=(WEDNESDAY TUESDAY SATURDAY)
declare -A map
for ((i=${#arr[@]}-1; i>=0; i--)); do 
    map[${arr[i-1]}]=${arr[i]}
done
```

This takes advantage of negative array indexes reading from the end of the array. Then:

```
for input in "${arr[@]}" SUNDAY; do 
    printf "%s => %s\n" "$input" "${map[$input]:-Null}"
done
```

```
WEDNESDAY => TUESDAY
TUESDAY => SATURDAY
SATURDAY => WEDNESDAY
SUNDAY => Null
```

Comment: @glennjackman my solution should contain the week days logic as well. It should know this order as well [SUNDAY,MONDAY,TUESDAY,WEDNESDAY,THURSDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY].

Its not about the Index position. Its about what comes before WEDNESDAY, TUESDAY and Saturday LOGICALLY.

Comment: Simply declare the source array as you want and my code will do what you want: `arr=(SUNDAY MONDAY TUESDAY WEDNESDAY THURSDAY FRIDAY SATURDAY)`.  bash array elements are not separated by commas nor are they surrounded by brackets, please stop using them. Why didn't you give this explicit information in your question?

Answer (score 0):

This can make it:

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#d[@]}; i++))
do
  [[ $((${#d[@]} - 1)) -eq $i ]] && next_index=0 || next_index=$((i+1))
  [ "$input" == "${d[$i]}" ] && echo "${d[$next_index]}"
done
```

It needs the input value to be stored in `$input`. Then it loops through the array and check if `$input` matches the record. If so, prints the next record in the array (`${d[$next_index]}`). In case it was the last one, it prints the first one.

To get the `$next_index` value, we use this is the ternary operator:

```
[[ $((${#d[@]} - 1)) -eq $i ]] && next_index=0 || next_index=$((i+1))
```

Which means:

```
if [[ $((${#d[@]} - 1)) -eq $i ]]; then
    next_index=0
else 
    next_index=$((i+1))
fi
```

That is, `$next_index` stores the index of the next item. In case it is the last one, it gets 0 (index of first item).

#### Test

```
$ d=(TUESDAY SATURDAY WEDNESDAY)
$ input=SATURDAY
$ for ((i = 0; i < ${#d[@]}; i++)); do [[ $((${#d[@]} - 1)) -eq $i ]] && next_index=0 || next_index=$((i+1)); [ "$input" == "${d[$i]}" ] && echo "${d[$next_index]}";  done
WEDNESDAY
$ input=TUESDAY
$ for ((i = 0; i < ${#d[@]}; i++)); do [[ $((${#d[@]} - 1)) -eq $i ]] && next_index=0 || next_index=$((i+1)); [ "$input" == "${d[$i]}" ] && echo "${d[$next_index]}";  done
SATURDAY
$ input=WEDNESDAY
$ for ((i = 0; i < ${#d[@]}; i++)); do [[ $((${#d[@]} - 1)) -eq $i ]] && next_index=0 || next_index=$((i+1)); [ "$input" == "${d[$i]}" ] && echo "${d[$next_index]}";  done
TUESDAY
$ input=SUNDAY
$ for ((i = 0; i < ${#d[@]}; i++)); do [[ $((${#d[@]} - 1)) -eq $i ]] && next_index=0 || next_index=$((i+1)); [ "$input" == "${d[$i]}" ] && echo "${d[$next_index]}";  done
$
```

Comment: I think you interpreted it wrongly might be i was not clear. I changed the body of the question, to correctly explain the use-case. It's little more complicated i think.

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal it does not make any sense now. Please try to make your question more clear, because having both `TUESDAY   ==> SATURDAY` and `WEDNESDAY ==> SATURDAY` breakes the "previous one" condition.

Comment: sry for that. I changed the question it should be TUESDAY ==> SATURDAY and WEDNESDAY ==> TUESDAY

Comment: The array index is evaluated in arithmetic context, so instead of `"${d[$((i+1))]}"` you can write `"${d[i+1]}"

Comment: What should happen when `input=WEDNESDAY`?

Comment: @glennjackman thanks! Finally it is not needed, but good to know :)

Comment: @glennjackman it should give Tuesday then, because according to the week days tuesday comes before Wednesday and tuesday is also presnt in the array. Suppose tuesday was not there then Saturday will be the output.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using the modulo operator `%`:

```
#! /bin/bash
previous=(WEDNESDAY TUESDAY SATURDAY)
for input in WEDNESDAY TUESDAY SATURDAY SUNDAY ; do
    for (( i=0; i<${#previous[@]}; i++ )) ; do
        [[ $input == ${previous[i]} ]] && break
    done
    if (( i < ${#previous[@]} )) ; then
        result=${previous[(i+1)%${#previous[@]}]}
    else
        result=Null
    fi
    echo $input $result
done
```

Or, in recent versions of bash supporting the associative arrays:

```
#! /bin/bash
previous_arr=(WEDNESDAY TUESDAY SATURDAY)
declare -A previous
for ((i=0; i<${#previous_arr[@]}; i++)) ; do
    p=${previous_arr[(i+1)%${#previous_arr[@]}]}
    previous[${previous_arr[i]}]=$p
done

for input in WEDNESDAY TUESDAY SATURDAY SUNDAY ; do
    echo $input ${previous[$input]}
done
```